# Memcpy failing when trying to copy variable on heap into shared memory in C

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory, memcpy

I'm trying to copy a struct I malloc'd and initialized on the heap into shared memory so that I can use the struct in child processes I want to fork. However, when I get to memcpy, I get the error that the address I'm trying to copy the struct to is an invalid address. I'm not sure where I messed up.

```
struct OverSharedData{
//pointers to other variables and structs
}

int main(){
struct OverSharedData* remp = (struct OverSharedData*)malloc(sizeof(struct OverSharedData));
initialize(remp);

key_t key = ftok("garbage.txt", 71);
int eyedee = shmget(key, sizeof(struct OverSharedData), IPC_CREAT);
struct OverSharedData* add = (struct OverSharedData *)shmat(eyedee, 0, 0);

memcpy(add, remp, sizeof(struct OverSharedData));
}
```

EDIT: Return values for add via gdb:

261 struct OverSharedData* add = (struct OverSharedData *)shmat(eyedee, 0, 0);

print add
$5 = (struct OverSharedData *) 0x8fe005ec
(gdb) next
263     memcpy(add, remp, sizeof(struct OverSharedData));
(gdb) print add
$6 = (struct OverSharedData *) 0xffffffff

Comment: You need to check the return values from `shmget` and `shmat`.  Either or both could have failed for any number of reasons.  See the man pages for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird, I encountered this exact same thing earlier today.

Add permissions to `shmget`:

```
int eyedee = shmget(key, sizeof(struct OverSharedData), 
                   IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP);
if (eyedee == -1)
{
    perror("shmget");
    exit(1);
}
```

Check the return code from `shmat`.

```
struct OverSharedData *add = (struct OverSharedData *) shmat(eyedee, 0, 0);
if (add == (void *) -1)
{
    perror("shmat");
    exit(1);
}
```